# Why doesn't this decode function working in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am debugging a python2 code:

```
tag_list = [convert(tag) for tag in tag_list]
print('tag_list: ', str(tag_list).decode("utf-8"))
```

However, the print out is like below:

```
u"['\\xe4\\xba\\xa4\\xe9\\x80\\x9a\\xe6\\x9c\\x8d\\xe5\\x8a\\xa1', '\\xe7\\xa4\\xbe\\xe4\\xbc\\x9a', '\\xe7\\x94\\xb5\\xe8\\xa7\\x86\\xe5\\x89\\xa7', '\\xe9\\x9f\\xb3\\xe4\\xb9\\x90']"
```

How to correctly print out the actual strings, instead of those x codes?

Comment: You are printing a string representation *of a list*.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you need the decode part?

Comment: Without that, it prints out all the codes, not strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("[" + ", ".join(tag_list) + "]")
```

I guess would give you the output you want ...  maybe

Comment: Yes， it worked. In Python3, it can print out good characters without doing a join(). Is that the diff between python 2 and 3?